Объясните, пожалуйста, почему документ ОказаниеУслуги создает две проводки в регистре бухгалтерии?
разъясните,пожалуйста, простым языком, почему  документ ОказаниеУслуги создает две проводки в регистре бухгалтерии :
Дт62 - Кт90 и Дт90 - Кт41;
подскажите еще в общем смысл счета 90(капитал);
я сейчас учу 1с по практическому руководству Хрусталевой .
Вот код :
// первая проводка: Д62(ДебиторскаяЗадолженность) - К90(капитал) Розничная сумма
Движение = Движения.Управленческий.Добавить();
Движение.КоличествоКт = ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.КоличествоВДокументе;
Движение.СчетДт = ПланыСчетов.Основной.ДебиторскаяЗадолженность;
 Движение.СчетКт = планыСчетов.Основной.Капитал;
  Движение.Период = Дата;
  Движение.Сумма = ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.СуммаВДокументе;
  Движение.СубконтоДт[ПланыВидовХарактеристик.ВидыСубконто.Клиенты] = Клиент;
  
  //Вторая проводка: Д90(Капитал) - К41(Товары) - себестоимость
  Движение = Движения.Управленческий.Добавить();
  Движение.СчетДт = ПланыСчетов.Основной.Капитал;
  Движение.СчетКт = ПланыСчетов.Основной.Товары;
  Движение.Период = Дата;
  Движение.Сумма = СтоимостьМатериала * ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.КоличествоВДокументе;
  Движение.КоличествоКт = ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.КоличествоВДокументе;
  Движение.СубконтоКт[ПланыВидовХарактеристик.ВидыСубконто.Материалы] = ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Номенклатура;

